# write file which packaged in apk in cocod2dx

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

My project have a "data" file which was located in assets folder. I read it by:

```
unsigned long buffer_size = 0;
unsigned char* file_buffer = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getFileData(CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->fullPathForFilename("data").c_str(), "r", &buffer_size);
```

But how to write it(append new data to this file)?
CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getWritablePath() return a different path than file located in assets. The path in my device is "/data/data/com.xxx.xxx/files/". If write to this path, a new file "data" will be created rather than modify the old one

Can file packaged in apk be updated?

Comment: if this is like on iOS (which I would expect) then apk like bundles are read-only

Comment: @LearnCocos2D is correct - you cannot modify files in your bundle. You would have to copy the file and then modify it in the copied location.